# It calculates the total number of missing values in each column of the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

To calculate the total number of missing values in each column of the dataframe, we use

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=0)
```

and to calculate the total number of missing values in each row of the dataframe, we use

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
```

This is counter-intuitive since axis = 0 is for rows and axis = 1 is for columns. Considering also that we use axis = 1 as below to drop columns

```
df = df.drop([]'BuildingArea','YearBuilt','CouncilArea'], axis=1)
```

Any help will be appreciated as i am stuck with this comprehension.

Comment: Yes, the axis parameter does flip flop depending on which method you are calling.  You can use axis='columns' or axis='rows' to make certain.

Comment: ` {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}` when you not quit used to the function, I recommend index and columns